# SAS list all file names issue (authorization to some files but not all)

Tags: sas, wrds-compusat, wrds

I am trying to use the following code to list all file names with a prefix in a folder and call a function named CALCU with the filenames:

```
  proc contents data=&libref.._all_ noprint out=contents; run;
  data _null_;
    set contents;
    by memname;
    if first.memname ;
    if upcase(memname) =: %upcase("&prefix");
    call execute(cats('%nrstr(%CALCU)(',memname,')'));
  run;
```

The code works fine when I have complete authorized access to all of the files in the directory. But now I found out that I actually don't have some access to some of the files with certain prefixes (luckily, I don't actually need those files that I don't have access to).

However, SAS just keeps throwing out errors like

```
ERROR: User does not have appropriate authorization level for file
       TAQ_CT.CTM_20120222.DATA.
```

Even though this is not the file I want.

I wonder how do I skip some of the files in the directory?

I have tried to delete everything else but the following line of code:

```
  proc contents data=&libref.._all_ noprint out=contents; run;
```

Still, it seems that I cannot even read the content properly when I don't have access to all of the files (SAS just keeps throwing out errors on the files that I don't have access to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a way to test this, but try `SASHELP.VMEMBER` instead of `PROC CONTENTS`

```
data _null_;
    set SASHELP.VMEMBER(where=(libname=upcase("&libref") and memtype = "DATA"));

    if upcase(memname) =: %upcase("&prefix");
    call execute(cats('%nrstr(%CALCU)(',memname,')'));
run;
```

This is a system view that lists all SAS files in a directory.  This way, you only try to access the ones you want.

Comment: it says `ERROR: File SASUSER.VMEMBER.DATA does not exist.` now

Comment: `SASHELP.VMEMBER` not `SASUSER`.

Comment: Whoops.  Sorry on the USER vs HELP